# FileUpload exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I try to open an Excel file but I have a probleme with fileUpload

when I write the path directly it works

```
EXCEL_CLASSEUR = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\WebTest\File.xlsx")
```

but when I use fileUpload and I select the same file path.

```
EXCEL_CLASSEUR = app.Workbooks.Open(Path.GetFileName(FileUploadtest.PostedFile.FileName))
```

I get Exception (sorry we can't find this file, maybe it's renamed or deleted)

Comment: Uploading a document does not automatically places it in the same directory. You need to specify it.

Comment: exactly,I mean I specify the same file with the same path in dialogue box. @VDWWD

Comment: In the code-behind, you should have specified a file location in the [SaveAs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: `Path.GetFileName()` will return only "File.xlsx". [This should help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload?view=netframework-4.8)